# Uncaught (in promise) Error:: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

1- I have a function to load all Regions from API, and it returns Regions as json.

2- The loading works correctly and displayed on screen (no error).

3- If I click to delete a Region, and then reload region Data after delete: 'regionsData = LoadRegionsAll();' I got this exception:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

---

I think a problem is with this line `'regionsData = LoadRegionsAll();'`
How can I reload the data after I made a delete operation.
I don't prefer to call an internal fetch inside the delete function, instead of that I just re-load the data by rest it into the defined variable ==> `'regionsData = LoadRegionsAll();'`

---

**LoadRegionsAll.js**

```
 import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
    const LoadRegionsAll = () => {
      const [error, setError] = useState("");
    
      const [regionsData, setRegionsData] = useState([]);
      let url = global.config.URL.Path + `/region`;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async (url) => {
          try {
            let response = await fetch(url, {
              headers: {
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
              },
            });
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error(
                `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`
              );
            }
            const actualData = await response.json();
    
            setRegionsData(actualData.result);
    
            console.log("## all regions ::: ", regionsData);
          } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
            console.log("## Error By Read Response Http  ::: ", err.message);
          } finally {
          }
        };
        getData(url);
      }, []);
      return regionsData;
    };
    
    export default LoadRegionsAll;

----
//Regions.js


    import Swal from "sweetalert2";
    import "../../../config";
    import "./Regions.css";
    import LoadRegionsAll from "./LoadRegionsAll";
    
    function Regions() {
      const [error, setError] = useState("");
      //const [regionsData, setRegionsData] = useState({});
    
      let regionsData = useRef();
    
      regionsData = LoadRegionsAll();
    
      function deleteRegion(Region) {
        Swal.fire({
          title: `Are you sure to delete: \n"${Region.regionName}"?`,
          showCancelButton: true,
        }).then((data) => {
          if (data.isConfirmed) {
            fetch(global.config.URL.Path + `/Region/${Region.id}`, {
              method: "DELETE",
            })
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((data) => {});
    
            regionsData = LoadRegionsAll();// this causes the error
          }
        });
      }
```

// here is my problem `regionsData = LoadRegionsAll();`
And if I changed to:

```
 const [regionsData, setRegionsData] = useState({});
 //let regionsData = useRef(); 
setRegionsData(LoadRegionsAll());
```

---

Then I got the following error: ERROR regionsData.map is not a function TypeError: regionsData.map is not a function at Regions (localhost:3000/main.84b65b4445c6b49f4a1b.hot-update.js:145:31) at renderWithHooks (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37259:22) at mountIndeterminateComponent